# how to fix npm: not found error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my first Jenkins pipeline project. I created a simple Node.js application, and I uploaded into hithub (public repo) and all I am trying to do with my Jenkinsfile is to "npm install" in my `Build` stage. I believe Jenkins is finding the `Jenkinsfile` but it is just not finding the `npm`. I am using `jenkins` official docker image to run my jenkins server. Here are the two plugging that I have installed

```
1) NodeJS Plugin and 2) Pipeline NPM Integration Plugin
```

and here is the file

```
 pipeline {                                                                                                       
     agent any
     stages {
        stage ("Build") {
           steps {
              sh "npm install"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

and this is the error I am getting when I run my 'Build Now'
     [second project] Running shell script
     + npm install

/var/jenkins_home/workspace/second project@tmp/durable-ef33ffd4/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/second    project@tmp/durable-ef33ffd4/script.sh:

> npm: not found

can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, your npm binary isn't in PATH variable.
Try to specify full path to npm, usually it's **/usr/bin**

```
 pipeline {                                                                                                       
     agent any
     stages {
        stage ("Build") {
           steps {
              sh "/usr/bin/npm install"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

You can check **npm** path in console using command `which npm`

Answer (score 0):

May be, you already figured this. Have you hosted your machine's docket socket in the container when you started the Jenkins container?

Specifically, you need use `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` on your docker run command.

Then in your pipeline, you need to run the `npm` on a docker container that is built it from official node docker image, such as `node:10.11.0-alpine`. Here is an example

```
pipeline {                                                                                                       
     agent {
        docker {
          image 'node:10.11.0-alpine'
        }
     }
     stages {
        stage ("Build") {
           steps {
              sh "npm install"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows than try to run CMD as Administrator and then install NPM it will work for you

Comment: I am on mac. my npm works if I do `npm install` on Terminal. It is just that not working from /on Jenkins.

Comment: try to login your mac as an administrator then try running the command again

Comment: I dont think you are understanding the problem/question. npm install works fine on Mac's terminal. It is just that Jenkins is not finding `npm`